# How to append an Instruction to a QuantumCircuit with variable length of QuantumRegisters as qargs?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

I *think* it is a bug but I'm not really sure. Basically, what I'm trying to do is the following: I have an Oracle Instruction which I want to append to my QuantumCircuit, looks as follows:

```
# initialising registers for readability
[control, train_register] = circ.qregs

circ.h(control)

# create and append oracle
oracle = create_oracle(train_register, control)  # returns an Instruction
circ.append(oracle, [train_register, control])
```

If my `train_register` and `control` are both `QuantumRegisters` with length 1, this works perfectly fine. But I want to make this work for variable length of these registers, I get the error `qiskit.circuit.exceptions.CircuitError: 'The amount of qubit arguments does not match the instruction expectation.'`.

This is logical, since this error occurs because qiskit checks the length of my provided `qargs` in `QuantumCircuit.append()`, and I provided two registers in a list with both one qubit, so the length of the list happens to be the same as the number of qubits.

However, I want this to work for variable length. If I *know* what the length of my `QuantumRegister`s are, say `len(train_register)` is 3 and `len(control)` is 1 I can use

```
circ.append(oracle, [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Or to make it work for unspecified lengths, I can write something like:

```
indices_to_append_to = list(np.arange(len(train_register) + len(control)))
circ.append(oracle, indices_to_append_to)
```

But I just really like the idea of just plugging in the names of the `qregs` as `qargs`. Is there something to make this work like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a list of qubits instead of a list of register this works. For this do

```
circ.append(oracle, train_register[:] + control[:])
```

where `train_register` and `control` are `QuantumRegister`s.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was almost a hundred percent certain I checked that possibility, but I think the way I did it was ```[train_register[:] + control[:]]```, which doens't work.